# Matching cards in Django, html and js

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

good evening everyone.
I have a list of random questions and answers, they're not very much different than matching cards.

I'm making them using Django library in python.

And I can't manage to make it to work, using html, js.

I tried couple of scripts but they all failed.

Here's the code:
views.py:

```
def homePage(request):
    objects = QuestionsAndAnswers.objects.values('question', 'answer', 'id')
    objects = sample(list(objects), 10)
    context = {
        'QuestionsRandom' : sample(list(objects), 10),
        'AnswersRandom' : sample(list(objects), 10),
    }
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', context=context)
```

homepage.html:

```
<div class='column1'>
      {% for result in QuestionsRandom %}
      <p><button class="questionCard" id="Q{{result.id}}" onclick="setColorQuestion('Q{{result.id}}')">
          <p style="color:black;margin: center;">{{forloop.counter}}</p>
          <p style="color:#4CAF50;font-size: 23px;text-align: center;">{{result.question}}</p>
        </button></p>

      {% endfor %}


    </div>
{% for result in AnswersRandom %}

      <p><button class="answerCard" id="A{{result.id}}" onclick="setColorAnswer('A{{result.id}}')">
          <p style="color:black">{{forloop.counter}}</p>
          <p style="color:rgb(228, 72, 72); font-size: 23px;padding: inherit;">{{result.answer}}</p>
        </button></p>

      {% endfor %}
```

I make the question's id and the answer's id invisible, so I can call them in the js script to check if they're the same then count a point to the team that opened the question card and the answer card correctly.

```
<script>  
  function checkingCard(choosedCardID) {
    var button = document.getElementById(choosedCardID);
    var style = getComputedStyle(button);
    var color = style['background-color'];
    
    
    if (choosedCardID.startsWith('Q') && color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {

      console.log('entering question, rgb is black');
      var questionCard = document.getElementsByClassName('questionCard')[choosedCardID]['id'];

    } else if (choosedCardID.startsWith('A') && color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
      console.log('entering answer, rgb is black');
      var answerCard = document.getElementsByClassName('answerCard')[choosedCardID]['id'];
      if (questionCard.replace('Q', '') == answerCard.replace('A', '')){

        var question = document.getElementById(questionCard);
        var answer = document.getElementById(answerCard);
        question.remove();
        answer.remove();   
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

There's two functions mentioned when a card is clicked, and when it's clicked it mentions this function `checkingCard` to check it and the card after it, but i'm not managing to get the two cards correctly.

Comment: Where are you calling the  `checkingCard` function? It isn't included anywhere in your html. I see you have a function called `setColorAnswer` and `setColorQuestion` which are called on the answer and question cards respectively but no `checkingCard`.

Comment: Hey Danarom, thanks for your time, I've already solved this issue I'll post the code tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:
basically just add an id to every card, the id will be the same on left and right but just in random places, and you'll check if the id matches, then it's correct.

the final code:

```
<script>
  
  var addedPoints = 0;
  var openedCards = [];
  var team = 'green';
  async function checkingCard(choosedCardID) {
    var button = document.getElementById(choosedCardID);
    var style = getComputedStyle(button);
    var color = style['background-color'];
    if (choosedCardID.startsWith('Q')) {
      openedCards[0] = (choosedCardID);
    } else if (choosedCardID.startsWith('A')) {
      openedCards[1] = (choosedCardID);
    }

    if (openedCards.length < 2) {



    } else if (openedCards.length == 2) {

      var question = openedCards[0].replace('Q', '');
      var answer = openedCards[1].replace('A', '');
      var ppQ = 'PPQ'.concat(question);
      var ppA = 'PPA'.concat(answer);
      var button1 = document.getElementById(openedCards[0]);
      var style1 = getComputedStyle(button);
      var color1 = style['background-color'];
      var button2 = document.getElementById(openedCards[1]);
      var style2 = getComputedStyle(button);
      var color2 = style['background-color'];
      if (question == answer && color1 != '#000' && color2 != '#000') {
        addPoint(team);
        await sleep(700);
        document.getElementById('PQ'.concat(question)).innerHTML = '✔';
        document.getElementById('PA'.concat(answer)).innerHTML = '✔';
        document.getElementById('PQ'.concat(question)).style.fontSize = '100px';
        document.getElementById('PA'.concat(answer)).style.fontSize = '100px';
        await sleep(1000);
        document.getElementById(openedCards[0]).remove();
        document.getElementById(openedCards[1]).remove();
        document.getElementById(ppQ).remove();
        document.getElementById(ppA).remove();
        addedPoints = addedPoints + 1;
        if (addedPoints == 2) {
          changeTeam();
          addedPoints = 0;
        }
        childs = document.getElementById('column1').childElementCount;
        if (childs == 1) {
          var lastID = document.getElementById('column1').children[0].id.replace('PPQ', '');
          document.getElementById('Q'.concat(lastID)).style.backgroundColor = '#000';
          document.getElementById('A'.concat(lastID)).style.backgroundColor = '#000';
          await sleep(1000);
          document.getElementById('Q'.concat(lastID)).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          document.getElementById('A'.concat(lastID)).style.backgroundColor = 'green';
          await sleep(500);
          document.getElementById('Q'.concat(lastID)).style.backgroundColor = '#000';
          document.getElementById('A'.concat(lastID)).style.backgroundColor = '#000';
          await sleep(1000);
          roundNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('roundNum').textContent) + 1;
          url = window.location.href;
          url = url.slice(0, -2);
          url = url.concat(String(roundNum))
          window.location.replace(url);
        }
      } else {
        addedPoints = 0;
        await sleep(2500);
        document.getElementById(openedCards[0]).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        document.getElementById(openedCards[1]).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        await sleep(1000);
        document.getElementById(openedCards[0]).style.backgroundColor = '#000';
        document.getElementById(openedCards[1]).style.backgroundColor = '#000';
        await sleep(500);
        setColor(openedCards[0]);
        setColor(openedCards[1]);
        changeTeam();
      }
      openedCards = [];
    }

  }
  function addPoint(team) {
    if (team == 'blue') {
      document.getElementById('bluePoints').textContent = parseInt(document.getElementById('bluePoints').textContent) + 1;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('greenPoints').textContent = parseInt(document.getElementById('greenPoints').textContent) + 1;
    }
  }

  function changeTeam() {

    if (team == 'blue') {
      team = 'green';
      document.getElementById('greenTeam').style.textShadow = '0 0 30px greenyellow';
      document.getElementById('blueTeam').style.textShadow = '0 0';
    } else {
      team = 'blue';
      document.getElementById('blueTeam').style.textShadow = '0 0 30px greenyellow';
      document.getElementById('greenTeam').style.textShadow = '0 0';
    }
  }
  function checkEndGame() {
    count = document.getElementById('column1').childElementCount;
    if (count == 0) {

    }
  }





</script>
```